# Get the name of a TypeScript class at runtime and use it in URL

Tags: angular, typescript, http, inheritance, get

I have seen several questions regarding getting the name of a typescript class upon runtime.

Currently I have something implemented along the lines of this.

```
export class ApiBase
{

  constructor()
  {
    const instance = new ApiBase();

    console.log(instance.constructor.name); 
    console.log(ApiBase.name);              
  }

}
```

However, I want to create a function and or class that inherits this ability and uses it to insert that class name into the URL. For example I have this class:

```
export class WeatherForecast {
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];
  public ID: any;
  forecast: any = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: ActivatedRoute) {
    http.get<any[]>('API/' + **CLASSNAMEHERE**  ).subscribe(result => {
      this.forecast = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

By doing this I should be able to have this service abstracted enough to be able to apply this to any controller or API rather than just my own. Am I on the right track? How might I complete this?

Comment: this.constructor.name?

Comment: This does work thank you. Perhaps I was overthinking my issue.

Comment: I would not rely on the class name, why not just pass a constructor parameter?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this perhaps? I'm not sure what you mean. I'm fairly new to typescript.

Comment: Coupling your UI class names to a REST url path segment is inherently fragile. As @AaronBeall suggested, it's much easier and better, IMO, to simply pass in the path segment.